# Get percentage of rows (strings) that fulfil a certain condition in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["Used", "Not used", "Not used", "Not used", "Used",
                         "Not used", "Used", "Used", "Used", "Not used"],
                   "B": ["Used", "Used", "Used", "Not used", "Not used",
                        "Used", "Not used", "Not used", "Used", "Not used"]})
```

I would like to find the quickest, cleanest way to find out the following:

- The percentage of rows of all the rows that have used A.
- The percentage of rows of all the rows that have used B.
- The percentage of rows of all the rows that have used A and B.

I am new to Python and pandas (and coding in general), so I am sure this is very simple, but any guidance would be appreciated. I have tried groupby().aggregate(sum) but I did not get the result I needed (I would imagine because these are characters rather than integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If need all values percentages use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `normalize=True`, for multiple columns [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for lengths of all pairs and divide it by `length of df` (same as length of index):

```
print (100 * df['A'].value_counts(normalize=True))
Not used    50.0
Used        50.0
Name: A, dtype: float64

print (100 * df['B'].value_counts(normalize=True))
Not used    50.0
Used        50.0
Name: B, dtype: float64

print (100 * df.groupby(['A','B']).size() / len(df.index))
A         B       
Not used  Not used    20.0
          Used        30.0
Used      Not used    30.0
          Used        20.0
dtype: float64
```

---

If need filter values create mask and get [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html) - `True`s are processed like `1`s:

```
print (100 * df['A'].eq('Used').mean())
#alternative
#print (100 * (df['B'] == 'Used').mean())
50.0

print (100 * df['B'].eq('Used').mean())
#alternative
#print (100 * (df['B'] == 'Used').mean())
50.0

print (100 * (df['A'].eq('Used') & df['B'].eq('Used')).mean())
20.0
```

Answer (score 6):

Use

1) Used A

```
In [4929]: 100.*df.A.eq('Used').sum()/df.shape[0]
Out[4929]: 50.0
```

2) Used B

```
In [4930]: 100.*df.B.eq('Used').sum()/df.shape[0]
Out[4930]: 50.0
```

3) Used A and Used B

```
In [4931]: 100.*(df.B.eq('Used') & df.A.eq('Used')).sum()/df.shape[0]
Out[4931]: 20.0
```

1) is same as

```
In [4933]: 100.*(df['A'] == 'Used').sum()/len(df.index)
Out[4933]: 50.0
```